# Access print jobs details using c# in mac os

Tags: c#, .net, macos

I had done with desktop application which override windows printing process, access print event, executing my own application when print job created, get all print jobs details such as:

- Printer name
- Doc name
- Time submitted
- No. of pages to be print

that all developed using c# .net and on windows platform,
But now i want to do same with MAC platform.
How i get all printing details as well as printing system events on Mac OS using DOT-NET.

Thanks in Advance,

Somesh patil

Comment: Hey somesh, were you able to port your aplication to mac? I would love to speak with you or if you could share some insights would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I would begin looking into Mono: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page. Microsoft does not provide a C# port for mac OS.

> Mono is a software platform designed to allow developers to easily
>   create cross platform applications. It is an open source
>   implementation of Microsoft's .Net Framework based on the ECMA
>   standards for C# and the Common Language Runtime. We feel that by
>   embracing a successful, standardized software platform, we can lower
>   the barriers to producing great applications for Linux.